# Delete duplicate files using Windows command line

Tags: batch-file

Given two directories c:\foo and c:\bar I want to delete the files in c:\bar that are identical to files present in c:\foo. I can use the fc command to compare each file in c:\bar with a file of the same name in c:\foo and delete duplicates manually. Is there a simple way to automate this using CMD?

Comment: The simple way to do this with a batch file is to write a Powershell script and call it from a batch file.

Comment: Do you mean `batch file` or `command line`?

Comment: A batch file or a one-liner that I can from the command line are both fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

cd c:\bar
for %%a in (*.*) do for %%b in ("c:\foo\%%a") do (
   if exist "%%b" (
      if "%%~Ta %%~Za" equ "%%~Tb %%~Zb" (
         del "%%a"
      ) else (
         fc "%%a" "%%b" > NUL
         if not errorlevel 1 del "%%a"
      )
   )
)
```

If two files may have different modification dates but be equal, remove the `%%~T..` parts in the comparison.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried running the the script, and it appears to delete the files that are *not* duplicates, not the ones that are.

Comment: Replacing "neq" with "equ" and adding a "not" before errorlevel 1 makes the code do what I want, thanks.

Comment: With `echo hello>c:\bar\diff&echo world>c:\foo\diff` your script will delete apparently _different_ files probably (false positive in `true` branch: different content although time and date and size the same). And with `echo hello>c:\bar\noex&del c:\foo\noex` (false positive in `else` branch: errorlevel 2)

Comment: Oops, now I see **no** false positive in `else` branch! Mea culpa!

Answer (score 4):

If **identical** means [similar or alike in *every* way](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/identical?s=t): in *every* way, not only in *date* and *size*, therefore forced **binary comparison**:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
pushd "D:\bat\FooBar"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /A:-D *.*') do (
  call :proFC "%%~fG" "D:\bat\FooFoo\%%~nxG"
)
popd
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:raiseerror
exit /B %1

:proFC
  call :raiseerror 321
  fc /B "%~1" "%~2" >NUL 2>&1
  if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo del "%~1"
  ) else (
    echo %errorlevel% "%~2"
  )
goto :eof
```

Commented crucial points in the above script:

- `pushd ...` switches current working directory
- `for /F ...` loop treats static file list of the *Bar* folder

  - `call :proFC ...` with properly quoted [line arguments parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- `popd` switches current working directory back
- `goto :eof` ends the script

`:raiseerror` subroutine returns exit code via `exit /B %1`

`:proFC` productive subroutine

- `call :raiseerror 321` **important** as [For an invalid switch (with two passed files) an error message is printed but the `errorlevel` is not changed](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html)
- `fc /B "%~1" "%~2" >NUL 2>&1` output and error messages [redirected](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to `NUL` as the errorlevel is important;
- `if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (`

  - `echo del "%~1"` a file delete merely _echo_ed for debugging purposes
- `) else (`

  - `echo %errorlevel% "%~2"` for debugging purposes (see below).
- `goto :eof` returns from the subroutine

`FC` will set an `ErrorLevel` as follows (but see a note at the `call :raiseerror 321` point):

```
-1 Invalid syntax (e.g. only one file passed) 
 0 The files are identical.
 1 The files are different.
 2 Cannot find at least one of the files.
```